# The Dreaded: No Android SDKs were found under the specified SDK location

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

Hoping, with some assistance, to find a solution here pls;

Environ: OSX 10.14.3 (Mojave)
Appcelerator: 
build: 5.1.1.201809051655
Build: jenkins-appcelerator-studio-titanium_studio-master-38 (master)
Date: 201809051655

Mac 64-bit installer downloaded from: https://platform.axway.com/#/product/studio

I originally attempted to install sdks via the button in the dashboard. The android sdk claimed it came down and was recognised as good. However the iOS sdk was problematic and just sat there spinning. I subsequently opened the App Store and d'loaded/installed XCode directly from there. Since then, it appears the Andoird sdks do not want to be recognised.

Things I have already attempted:

- moved the 'android-sdk-macosx' dir out of the Library dir.
- deleted the .titanium dir and restarted. The subsequently created config.json does list the correct sdk base dir.
- *(Not tried as such, but:)* No Genymotion installed
- The sdk dir *is* listed in the Prefs Dialog > Platforms > Android, but the error is recognised.
- Instructions followed @: https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Errors_Configuring_Platforms_Inside_Studio

There is no mention of 'avd.py' in the log. 
Surely, this indicates there is no Python installed, no......? And if no python is installed, how could a script expected to run in order to recognise the android sdk physically run?

- Output of 'appc ti config'

  macbook:~ me$ appc ti config
  Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 7.0.9
  Copyright (c) 2014-2019, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

  android.sdkPath        = "/Users/me/Library/android-sdk-macosx/"
  app.workspace          = ""
  cli.colors             = true
  cli.completion         = false
  cli.failOnWrongSDK     = false
  cli.httpProxyServer    = ""
  cli.ignoreDirs         = "^(\.svn|_svn|\.git|\.hg|\.?[Cc][Vv][Ss]|\.bzr|\$RECYCLE\.BIN)$"
  cli.ignoreFiles        = "^(\.gitignore|\.npmignore|\.cvsignore|\.DS_Store|\._.*|[Tt]humbs.db|\.vspscc|\.vssscc|\.sublime-project|\.sublime-workspace|\.project|\.tmproj)$"
  cli.logLevel           = "trace"
  cli.progressBars       = true
  cli.prompt             = true
  cli.rejectUnauthorized = true
  cli.width              = 100
  paths.commands         = []
  paths.hooks            = []
  paths.modules          = []
  paths.plugins          = []
  paths.sdks             = []
  paths.templates        = []
  user.locale            = "en_US"
- Output of 'appc ti info -t android'. I note here "Android Executable = not found". That must surely be significant??

  macbook:~ me$ appc ti info -t android
  Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 7.0.9
  Copyright (c) 2014-2019, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

  Android SDK
    Android Executable          = not found
    ADB Executable              = /Users/me/Library/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb
    SDK Path                    = /Users/me/Library/android-sdk-macosx

  Android NDK
    NDK Path                    = not found
    NDK Version                 = not found

  Android Platforms
    1) android-23
      Name                      = Android 6.0
      API Level                 = 23
      Revision                  = 3
      Skins                     = HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800, WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in, AndroidWearRound, AndroidWearRound360x360, AndroidWearRound400x400, AndroidWearRound480x480, AndroidWearRoundChin320x290, AndroidWearRoundChin320x300, AndroidWearRoundChin360x325, AndroidWearRoundChin360x326, AndroidWearRoundChin360x330, AndroidWearSquare, AndroidWearSquare240x240, AndroidWearSquare320x320
      ABIs                      = armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64
      Path                      = /Users/me/Library/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-23
    2) android-28
      Name                      = Android 9
      API Level                 = 28
      Revision                  = 1
      Skins                     = HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800, WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in, AndroidWearRound, AndroidWearRound360x360, AndroidWearRound390x390, AndroidWearRound400x400, AndroidWearRound454x454, AndroidWearRound480x480, AndroidWearRoundChin320x290, AndroidWearRoundChin320x300, AndroidWearRoundChin360x325, AndroidWearRoundChin360x326, AndroidWearRoundChin360x330, AndroidWearSquare, AndroidWearSquare240x240, AndroidWearSquare320x320
      ABIs                      = x86, x86_64
      Path                      = /Users/me/Library/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-28

  Android Add-Ons
    3) Google Inc.:Google APIs:23
      Name                      = Google APIs (Android 6.0 (API level 23))
      Vendor                    = Google Inc.
      Revision                  = 1
      Description               = Android + Google APIs
      Skins                     = HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800, WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in, AndroidWearRound, AndroidWearRound360x360, AndroidWearRound400x400, AndroidWearRound480x480, AndroidWearRoundChin320x290, AndroidWearRoundChin320x300, AndroidWearRoundChin360x325, AndroidWearRoundChin360x326, AndroidWearRoundChin360x330, AndroidWearSquare, AndroidWearSquare240x240, AndroidWearSquare320x320
      ABIs                      = armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64
      Path                      = /Users/me/Library/android-sdk-macosx/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-23
      Libraries                 = none

  Android Emulators
    titanium_1_WVGA800
      ID                        = titanium_1_WVGA800
      SDK Version               = Android 6.0 (API level 23)
      ABI                       = armeabi-v7a
      Skin                      = wvga800
      Path                      = /Users/me/.android/avd/titanium_1_WVGA800.avd
      SD Card                   = /Users/me/.android/avd/titanium_1_WVGA800.avd/sdcard.img
      Google APIs               = no

  Genymotion Emulators
    None

  Connected Android Devices
    None

  Android Issues
    !  Unable to locate an Android NDK.
       Without the NDK, you will not be able to build native Android Titanium modules.
       If you have already downloaded and installed the Android NDK, you can tell Titanium where the
       Android NDK is located by running 'appc titanium config android.ndkPath /path/to/android-ndk',
       otherwise you can install it by running 'appc titanium setup android' or manually downloading
       from http://appcelerator.com/android-ndk.
- Finally, in light of the apparently missing 'avd.py' ref. and the apparently missing Android Executable, I have since re-d'loaded the Studio from the above link, and re-installed it.

I then clicked on configure for the Android sdk, which when finished showed me all Ticks, but to no avail. Both the prefs dialog and the Dashboard claim it still ain't there.

[Android SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwhIr.png)

I would really appreciate your assistance.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: P.S. I've read over the years on Stack, people requesting <x> post be put in <y> forum. I did look for that when creating, but could not find anything obvious. So, if it needs go somewhere else, pls do just move it and enlighten me for the future.

Comment: Bump. 

Can anyone offer some insight here please?

Answer (score 1):

> Android Executable = not found

I think you miss the `tools` directory in the sdk (with Android Studio's SDK Manager I had to install `Android SDK Tools`).

I'd suggest to download the Android SDK with Android Studio or standalone from Google and then add the sdk path in Appcelerator Studio settings (Platform -> Android).

Answer (score 0):

1. Completely uninstall (remove every installed file) the android studio and install it again.

2.U can also download sdk and ndk inside android studio -> sdk manager

Comment: "uninstall the ** Android Studio **" I don't have the Android Studio app installed. Just the sdks.

Or do you mean the Appcelerator Studio? I have tried that, although I admit it had apparently left some log files around. But where do I find the remaining files it leaves behind when dragging the app to trash?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to place your "android-sdk" folder to the Home directory and show the location to the Axway Appcelerator Studio>>Preferences>>Studio>>Platforms>Android>Android SDK Home.
Then click on Install SDKs>> Now select android 6.X.X, 7.X.X,8.X.X and install those packages.

If you face any issue then try to setup android SDK via the terminal.

- appc ti config android.sdk SDKLocation
- appc ti setup android

And restart PC.

Also, take a look android SDK installation guide -
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_the_Android_SDK

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had that exact problem, but somewhere in the appcelerator docs (https://docs.axway.com/bundle/Titanium_SDK_allOS_en/page/installing_the_android_sdk.html) was an instruction to also install android studio at https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html.

After installing android studio and using that the menu on the bottom: configure -> sdk manager to download SDKs, my Appcelerator studio worked. I still can't use appcelerator studio to get more SDKs, but the android studio path at least has me working again.